# Uninstall CouchDB Completely Mac OSX

Tags: couchdb, osx-mavericks, addremoveprograms

I've played around with my couchdb configuration and I would like to start fresh again, remove the app and downloading a new one didn't seem to remove the configuration completely, where I still have to access with my username and password, and my dbs are still there.

Looking around on internet, I don't seem to find a solution to fix the issue on mac os x (mavericks)

Well, I've done some things like:

- removing the cache folder from `~/Library/Caches`
- removing *any* related file/folder in `~/Library/Application Support/CouchDB`
- checking the config file from `~/Library/Preferences/couchdb-server.ini` seems to be an alias to config file in `Application Support` CouchDB folder
- I also removed a couple of *files* that I don't remember their names

Still installing a fresh download couchdb is not working application and now I am getting the json message: 
**{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"Name or password is incorrect."}**

P.S: My System is **Mac OS X Mavericks** and **Couchdb 1.5.1**

Comment: Your question got downvoted (wasn't me) because it it not programming related. It's about uninstalling software. These kind of questions are better suited on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) (or maybe [DBA.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: Thank you @Simon, I understand that, but a close vote is more appropriate in this case, but well it doesn't matter anymore :)

Comment: God this site is so pedantic.

Comment: For the record this did help me and it is kind of programming related because I want to test using CouchDB installed on the client side with an web app I've made and I need to do a fresh install to fully test and document that process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it seems I've found the missing file very soon, after I posted my question, so for anyone who gets this problem in future, this is the culprit file:

```
/Users/kouiti/Library/Preferences/org.apache.couchdb.plist
```